# Kafka Connect azure-data-lake-gen2-connector fails with below error when using avro converter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to write the ADLS genn 2 in parquet format.

```
format.class: io.confluent.connect.azure.storage.format.parquet.ParquetFormat
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

> io.confluent
> kafka-connect-avro-converter
> 7.2.1

kc_config.yaml

```
    key.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    connector.class:io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.AzureDataLakeGen2SinkConnector
    storage.class: io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.storage.AzureDataLakeGen2Storage
    azure.datalake.gen2.account.name: ${ADLS_ACCOUNT_NAME}
    azure.datalake.gen2.access.key: ${AZURE_KEY}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.getLatestCompatibilityStrict()Z
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:55)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.<init>(AvroConverter.java:145)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:77)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:293)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:446)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1700(DistributedHerder.java:125)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:1155)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:1151)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: You'll also need kafka-avro-serializer dependency

Comment: I've added the below dependency and still the same exact issue.

<!--     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: To fix "no such method" errors, you'd probably need to use a version newer than 3.3.1. For example, your converter is using 7.2.1, so use the same for the serializer. You also should not really need the converter in your Java program. That should be reserved for the Connect workers themselves